# white screen to implement ngCordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Had in my project implemented ngCordova, besides, I added ngCordovaOauth to generate login with facebook and twitter in my application this is where the problem came. After installing bower and then ng-cordova-oauth received the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionicApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCordova due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCordova' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Then delete the reference to ng-cordova-oauth and the problem persisted. Now I could not fix it and every time I run my application is all white and throws this error.

in my index.html file is the reference to the ng-cordova.min.js file and this is my angular module

```
angular.module('SharedServices', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngMap','openfb'])
```

Comment: does all js are included correctly?

Comment: yes, in fact, I stopped working all for me since bower and install ng-cordova-oauth

Comment: Your issue seems really linked to the lack of ng-cordova.js. verify that you have it and it is properly loaded.

Comment: effectively check the file and it was fine. Let solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

effectively check the file and it was fine. Run, `bower install -SF ngCordova` then made reference to the file installed and run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110942/how-to-include-ngcordova-and-cordova-in-index-html